# Leetcode: My solution works for Individual test cases but not for All test cases together

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

This is Leetcode question no: 940. Distinct Subsequences II

My code is using Recursion to fetch the subsequences. And I am using an external HashSet to keep count of the unique subsets. The reason I am subtracting one from the size is to incorporate for the empty string because as per the solution we are not supposed to include the empty string. When I run the code for individual test cases, it runs fine. But when the test cases are run together consecutively, my solution is deemed wrong. Can anybody point me in the direction as to where I could be going wrong in my code? Is it to do with the Set usage or the recursion code itself? I am aware that this problem can be solved using Dynamic Programming(which I am yet to tackle), but I just wanted to know if there is a solution possible through Recursion ??

Please refer attached images for solution and test cases runs:

[Code that I have written on Leet code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk0Af.png)

[The individual test cases that I have run on Leetcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sgUJ.png)

[The joint test cases run by Leetcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHhpF.png)

Code:

```
class Solution {
    
    static Set<String> myset = new HashSet<String>(0);
    public int distinctSubseqII(String s) {
    int i=0;
    String curr="";
    subsets(s, curr, i);
    int val = myset.size()-1;
    return val;
    }
    
    
    public static void subsets(String str,String curr,int i){
    
    if(i==str.length()){
        //System.out.println(curr);
        myset.add(curr);
        return; 
    }
    subsets(str, curr, i+1);
    subsets(str, curr+str.charAt(i), i+1);   
}
    
}
```

Comment: Post code and errors and results as text, not as screenshots. The cause is probably the set being static.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to make the functions and fields static?

Comment: Indeed, the `static` fields are the most likely cause of what you are seeing.  State is probably "leaking" from one test to the next via the `static` fields.  Basically, that is a bug in your code.

Comment: @justanotherguy I can make the recursive function non-static but I am using the set outside the function as a global variable. I did try to use it within the recursive function, but it becomes messy and complex. That is the only reason that I have declared my set as static. At this point I am of the opinion that the static on the set is messing up the code.

Comment: @StephenC I believe you are right. I am looking into this and seeing if there is any other way I can modify this to function as it should. Any suggestions at the top of your head? Declaring the set inside the recursive function is messing up my code. How else can I declare a set outside of a function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I can see that the `static` variable is the problem.  The contents of that `Set` carry over from one call of `distinctSubseqII` to the next.   That means that the size of the `Set` will be wrong ... for the second and all later calls.

Cutting to the chase ...

You need to do the recursion in a [helper function](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Em.neumann/fall2015/cse200/lectures/6/Recursion#10).

In your example, it might look like this.

```
public class Solution {
   
    public int distinctSubseqII(String s) {
        Set<String> myset = new HashSet<String>(0);
        return recursive(s, mySet);
    }

    // Helper function
    private int recursive(String s, Set<String> mySet) {
        ...
        // call 'recursive' ... recursively
        ...
    }
}
```

The "helper function" is a common pattern for recursive solutions.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I did edit my code around a bit to get rid of the static Set and tried a slightly different approach with the recursive function, and it worked! However, LeetCode is not very happy with the solution as it gave me a "Time Limit Exceeded" exception and that is understandable as they expect a better algorithmic solution which I believe can be achieved through Dynamic Programming. Anyhow I am satisfied that I was atleast able to debug the issue. Thank you so much for your inputs!